# How can I configure local deploy and remote via command line?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I wondering if it possible to deploy code to local machine without changing everywhere from "run" to "run_locally"?

For example, I have production server and Jenkins server. On production, tasks compile assets and etc. On Jenkins server I don't need to run on remote server, but only on Jenkins.

I can use "run_locally", but I don't like idea to duplicate my tasks and get human mistakes.

Ideal solution is to switch "run" and "run_locally" with cmd argument, like "cap deploy --locally"

Answer (score 0):

I think, different stages is what are you looking for.

[Capistrano multistage](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension) should help

Also, you can achieve the same [as described here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multiple-Stages-Without-Multistage-Extension)